# How to send mapped data as props to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to send mapped data as props to another component.

My code looks like this:

```
<div className={styles.myTeamFlex}>
  {userTeams.map((team, index) => (
    <TeamCard
      key={team + index}
      active={active}
      index={index}
      data={team}
      teamRoles={userTeamRoles}
      setactive={setactive}
    />
  ))}
</div>;
```

and I want to fetch this data in another component as well like I have another
component and I exported the above component in that component but map method doesn't work and throws
an error:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How is `userTeams` declared? What is its value on the initial render? Value on subsequent renders? How is it updated? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: You will need to check if userTeams is an `Array`, add this check `Array.isArray(userTeams)` before mapping it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when defining the state you didn't set the default value to `[]`.

Try this:

```
const [userTeams, setUsersTeam] = useState([]); // Note []
```

Another option will be to check `userTeams` before mapping it.
Change this line:

```
{userTeams.map((team, index) => (
```

to

```
{usersTeam && userTeams.map((team, index) => (
```

Answer (score 0):

you must check userTerms to be Array

```
<div className={styles.myTeamFlex}>
  {userTeams&&userTeams.lenght>0&&userTeams.map((team, index) => (
    <TeamCard
      key={team + index}
      active={active}
      index={index}
      data={team}
      teamRoles={userTeamRoles}
      setactive={setactive}
    />
  ))}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import TeamCard from "./teamCard";

export default function App() {
  let TeamArray = [
    { name: "team1", color: "blue" },
    { name: "team2", color: "red" },
    { name: "team3", color: "green" }
  ];
  console.log(TeamArray);
  return (
    <div>
      {TeamArray.map((team, index) => (
        <TeamCard key={team.name + index} data={team} idIndexObject={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Children.js

```js
const TeamCard = ({ data, idIndexObject }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <h2>{data.color}</h2>
      <h3>{idIndexObject}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TeamCard;
```

check sandbox =>

[image: Edit competent-bhabha-32niy]

please update your post for a better visual presentation next time